# Hoping something for the future

Tags: tense, syntax, future-tense

When you want to say that you hope or expect that something happens to someone, but in some moment in the future, what sentence is the right one:

> I hope your holidays **will** be great.
>   I hope **that** your holidays **will** be great.
>   I hope your holidays are great.

Comment: If you *wish* great holidays to someone, you may break the rules by saying, "***wish you** great holidays*"

Comment: Another way to say this would be, "I hope you have a great holiday," but there's nothing wrong with the samples in this question, either.

Comment: This is really two totally separate questions in one. Firstly, does it make any difference whether you include the optional "that"? (imho, no). Secondly, can you use present tense for something you hope *will* happen in the future. In this example, you can - it's entirely a stylistic choice, but most native speakers would usually use present tense here.

Answer (score 2):

All three of the forms you gave are fine and none would cause any confusion.

It *may* be that the third form, "I hope your holidays are great", is slightly grammatically incorrect, since you are hoping for something in the future but using "are", the plural present tense of the verb "to be". However, it is a *very* common construct, at least in spoken English.

In fact, consider the following two alternate versions of the forms you gave:

> Enjoy your holidays! I hope **they'll be** great.
>
> Enjoy your holidays! I hope **they're** great.

In this case, the first form, while possibly more "correct", feels awkward, while the second form flows nicely and is, for me at least, the preferred format.

Comment: Yes except I wouldn't dignify that "grammatically incorrect" business with anything as acquiescent/accepting as "it may be". Anyone who advanced that proposition would be a scurrilous pedant! Should we not dare say *"I hope it's a good film!"*, or *"I hope it's sunny on our wedding day"* for fear of the grammar police?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Point taken. All three are equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

Both:

> I hope your holidays **will** be great.
>
> I hope **that** your holidays **will** be great.

Are quite acceptable and would be easily understood by anyone; although the first one is a bit on the informal side.

Comment: It may be slightly informal, but there's no slang in it.  Also, In this case, *I hope your holidays* **are** *great*" may  actually be more common than the future *will be*.

Comment: I don't agree there's anything to this more/less "informal" business. Or, by implication, that one is more "formal" than the other.